Pillow creating errors when resizing image
# Downloads image
def downloadImage(imageUrl, savePath):
    # Send a GET request to the URL
    response = requests.get(imageUrl)

    # Check if the request was successful
    if response.status_code == 200:
        # Open the image using PIL
        img = Image.open(BytesIO(response.content))

        # Resize the image to 512x512
        img = img.resize((512, 512), Image.BICUBIC)

        # Save the resized image
        img.save(savePath)

I wrote this code to download an image from a URL, and then resize the image to 512x512 with Pillow. For some reason, when the image gets saved, there are strange artifacts. Below I have included two images. On the left is the original image resized in Photoshop, on the right is the image resized with Pillow. Especially around the curves, such as around the eyes, you can see strange almost bump like artifacts. Does anyone know why this is happening?


Unfortunately your code is incomplete, so we can't see what you actually downloaded or where from. Also, you have joined the two images into one so we can't see what's actually happened to the individual images.
